# How do you return a value from a MySQL table after inserting a row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have page I have written in PHP. I am inserting a couple values as a row in one of my tables. One of the columns on that table is `test_id`. I want, when I INSERT the rows it to return the `test_id` of that row. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this function `mysql_insert_id`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: what do you put in the parenthesis? the result of the query? or the database connection? because I tried both of those and it said they were invalid.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (field) values ('value')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the id of the most recent insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysql function LAST_INSERT_ID() to find the ID that was inserted. Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```

Answer (score 1):

If this row is an AUTO_INCEREMENT row, you can call mysql_insert_id() function to retrieve the  id of the last row inserted.